# Probability of probability...

Tags: probability

I would like to understand the topic "Probability of Probability"

Consider the standard dice problem. We have a regular dice. We know very well that if we throw it indefinitely, then the probability of one of the six numbers falling out will be equal to $1/6$

Now, let's say that with a probability of $1/6$ we will get one of the six numbers of the cube - this is our event

How to find the probability of our event?
Let me rephrase the question in a more formal way: What is the probability that with a probability of $1/6$ we will get one of the six numbers of the cube?

Comment: Probabilities can only be evaluated when there is a probability model. You describe some event for which no probability model has been precisely specified.  So it cannot be answered. Having said that, we usually assume that any throw of a 6-sided die will **always** yield one of the six numbers on that cube.  We do not consider the negligible probability that the die lands on one of its corners.

Comment: Isn't there a concept of "Probability of Probability" in the world?

Comment: Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ can describe such a thing via conditional probability.  For example $X \in \{0, 1\}$ Bernoulli and $P[Y\leq y|X=0]$ and $P[Y\leq y|X=1]$.

Comment: I did some reading and this is what I found out

We assume (it has nothing to do with the cube) that they are from normal with parameters like that. Then we need to specify expectation and variance, and then there is the Lagrange method - we need to maximize the likelihood function

And as the answer we will have a function of these two parameters, which is called the confidence level. The higher it is, the greater the "probability" that you have guessed the distribution correctly. In a sense, this is finding the probability from the likelihood

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Perhaps you are trying to ask a question about real world probabilities?  If so:  Of course it is the case that actual dice have imperfections, so naturally the $\frac 16$ is not perfectly realized.  Should be close, but as a practical matter you couldn't tell $p=\frac 16$ from $\frac 16 -\epsilon <p<\frac 16 +\epsilon$ for some extremely small $\epsilon$.  With that model, then the actual probability is a continuous variable with some distribution tightly centered around $\frac 16$.  But then, the probability that the actual probability is exactly $\frac 16$ is $0$.